# WeakBox requires that WeakArray<Element>.Element be a class type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a storing weak references solutions from objc talks (https://www.objc.io/blog/2017/12/28/weak-arrays/) but I'm not able to get it working.

The exact error message tells:

```
'WeakBox' requires that 'WeakArray<Element>.Element' (aka 'Optional<Element>') be a class type
```

[image]

With this code:

```
final class WeakBox<A: AnyObject> {
    weak var unbox: A?

    init(_ value: A) {
        unbox = value
    }
}

struct WeakArray<Element: AnyObject> {
    private var items: [WeakBox<Element>] = []

    init(_ elements: [Element]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakBox($0) }
    }

    init() {}
}

extension WeakArray: Collection {
    var startIndex: Int { return items.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return items.endIndex }

    subscript(_ index: Int) -> Element? {
        return items[index].unbox
    }

    func index(after idx: Int) -> Int {
        return items.index(after: idx)
    }

    mutating func append(_ element: Element) {
        items.append(WeakBox(element))
    }

    mutating func removeAll() {
        items.removeAll()
    }
}
```

**

### Update:

**

After some time I realized that error message is completely misleading. The real problem is in calling methods of a **Sequence** protocol. For example, adding something like this below produces an error message from the above screenshot. But I haven't found a solution yet.

```
    class De {
        let de = "de"
    }

    let de = De()
    var ar = WeakArray<De>([])
    ar.append(de)
    ar.append(de)

    ar.forEach({ $0 })
```

Comment: Updated a question with a screenshot of an error message.

Comment: Where are you testing your code? I cannot reproduce the error using the code in your question in a playground using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put an Optional into this array. Is that correct? How are you using this?

Comment: @RobNapier No, please check updated question for more details.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with your example. It seems to work fine (except for the expected "Expression of type 'De?' is unused" warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe 'Element' is being redefined by the SDK somewhere. Renaming Element to T should fix the issue.

```
import Foundation

final class WeakBox<T:AnyObject> {
    weak var unbox: T?
    init(_ value: T?) {
        unbox = value
    }
}

struct WeakArray<T: AnyObject> {
    private var items: [WeakBox<T>] = []

    init(_ elements: [T]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakBox($0) }
    }

    init(_ elements: [T?]) {
        items = elements.map { WeakBox($0) }
    }

    mutating func append(_ obj:T?) {
        items.append(WeakBox(obj))
    }

    mutating func remove(at:Int) {
        items.remove(at: at)
    }
}

extension WeakArray: Collection {
    var startIndex: Int { return items.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { return items.endIndex }

    subscript(_ index: Int) -> T? {
        return items[index].unbox
    }

    func index(after idx: Int) -> Int {
        return items.index(after: idx)
    }
}
```